# Positioning text on top of text

Tags: html, css

I have a font that has a fill and a shadow so they need to be used together, the fill on top and the shadow underneath. I've been able to layer over the other like so: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxpUM.jpg)

I did this with relative and absolute positioning:

**HTML:**

```
 <h1 class="fill">TEXT</h1>
 <h1 class="shadow">TEXT</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fill {
    font-family: "Tilastia-Fill";
    position: relative;
}

.shadow {
    font-family: "Tilastia-Shadow";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

I'm struggling with preserving the right look when the orientation of the screen changes from portrait to landscape, especially when I include multiple lines of double stacked text. For example, when the orientation of the screen changes to landscape the result is: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maCt5.png)

Obviously things have jumped around and there's something fundamental about positioning I'm not understanding.

Comment: You can simply use `text-shadow`: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_shadows.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can make them stick together by adding a parent div with a relative position

and make both text positioned according to this div with same css

this how the code should look like

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

.fill {
    font-family: "Tilastia-Fill";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.shadow {
    font-family: "Tilastia-Shadow";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    
}
```

```html
 <div>
 <h1 class="fill">TEXT</h1>
 <h1 class="shadow">TEXT</h1>
 </div>
```

and if you want one to move a little more then the other you can play with `left, right, top , bottom`

and you should use pixels instead of %

and you can see an example of that [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/veyp45xg/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: i'm glad it helped :)